# display local existing pdf file with pdf.js library into electron app context

Tags: javascript, pdf, electron

I have an Electron.js app project which already contains pdf files locally.

I installed pdf.js and I already test the pdfjs/web/viewer.html to render a pdf test file which render very well.

I need to render other pdf files of my project. But I don't understand how because all of explanations are based in a concept of file is remote or uploaded or app is a web app. *In my case I don't have anything about web server or upload file or remote. Just local already existing file.*

If a understand pdf.js library I need to create this kind of url for display my pdf into a BrowserWindow electron :

```
'web/viewer.html?file=' + url'
```

and I understand need to encode this url var because my file is not affordable by direct url. But I don't understand the steps for created that.

**- I need to stream the content of the file ?**

**- I need to create a File Object ?**

**- I need to create a Blob or Base64 object ?**

**- If a can't use URL.createObjectURL(), how generate url that representing this pdf file ?**

**- What is the order process to respect ?**

At this point I coding that :

```
function getFileObject(filepath)
{
    let filePath = path.join(__static, filepath)
    return fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
}

fileObject = util.getFileObject('../data/files/xxxxxx/xxx.pdf')
objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileObject)
```

But URL is not recognize by my node.js electron environment. And I don't sure that is the good way. It seems that is render pdf job is so tricky and I need a few advices community.